# Q. Extracting db schema generation scripts using pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I would like to extract database table generation scripts using PyMysql. When I execute a statement like cursor.execute("show create table table_name;") it does not return the expected result.

Comment: What does it return then?

Comment: It doesn't seem to return anything. I tried checking the cursor variable in debug mode and there isn't any useful information related to the query that just got executed.